# Isn't it misleading to call written representations of spoken languages as written languages?

Tags: terminology, writing-systems, written-language, spoken-language

*In the following sentences I would refer to anything that can be used to denote something as a symbol.*

---

Any language uses some kind of symbol to denote different things. I presume that any language for which the symbols are speech sounds is called a spoken language. To overcome the limitations of spoken languages we have developed their written representations. It is common for people to call such written representations of spoken languages [written languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Written_language#:%7E:text=A%20written%20language%20is%20the%20representation%20of%20a%20spoken%20or%20gestural%20language%20by%20means%20of%20a%20writing%20system.%5B1%5D).

My question is isn't it a bit misleading to call the written representation of a spoken language a written language?

I think it is more accurate to call something a written language that intrinsically uses written symbols to denote things rather than something which is just a representation of speech sounds.

Consider a language where ')' denotes the idea of *let*, '->' denotes the idea of *go*, and '~' denotes the idea of swimming. Then in such a language if I wanted to communicate *let's go swimming* I could write )->~. This would be a language for which symbols are intrinsically written and hence could be called a written language (just as we called a language for which the symbols were intrinsically speech sounds a spoken language).

Comment: Why is it misleading? Surely if I write English down on paper, that becomes "written English".

Comment: /bət ðerz 'rɪtən 'ɪŋɡlɪʃ, ən ðɛn ðerz 'rɪtən 'ɪŋɡlɪʃ./

Comment: @Draconis It seems misleading to me because won't a written language be the one that is in and of itself rather than being a helping hand for a spoken language?

Comment: @Draconis I think much of my confusion is arising because of imprecise definitions. Is there a precise definition for spoken and written languages in linguistics?

Comment: There are languages that have no writing system. They are therefore not written languages. A written language is an accepted term in linguistics and means there is a written form for a language that is spoken. Of course, you can make up a written language and neve speak it.

Answer (score 0):

A statement is misleading when it is made in an attempt to deceive a person by secretly intending interpretation X while knowing that addresses are most likely to interpret the statement as meaning substantially different Y. A confusing statement differs from a misleading statement in lacking the intent to deceive, though also a confusing statement is likely to have multiple easily accessible interpretations.

The thing that you are talking about is known, in some linguistic circles, as "E-language", that is, the external manifestation of a mental faculty. E-language is a big tent, including manifestations of a language and social correlates of a language (E.g. the social fact that you should not call your grandfather "bitch"). E-language corresponds to ordinary notions of language, and I-language (internal/intensional) is a term of art used by some linguists.

In the E-language sense, some languages are written and dead (Sumerian, Middle English), some are written and alive (Modern English, Mandarin). "Live" and "dead" are scalar terms, thus Sanskrit is somewhat alive – it has fluent second-language speakers and it is written. Lushootseed has no fluent speakers but it has some (not sure what adjective to use) speakers, and it also is written. Sentinelese is a spoken language that is (absolutely) not written, Tepes is a language which some linguists have transcribed bits of but which has no generally-adopted writing system. Norwegian has two official written forms, Nynorsk and Bokmål, which are not or have not been spoken languages, instead there are various spoken dialects that could be closer to Nynorsk or Bokmål in some respect.

"Spoken language" is fairly straightforward. It means "the spoken output of people who speak X". "Written language" is vague, because it can refer to a number of different things. Typically it has a normative import, that this is how the language *should* be written. Normative claims about language flagrantly ignore that facts of spoken language. Normative statements about dead languages are rather pointless. Normative statements about living languages can at least be evaluated by reference to some social goal, such as "literacy". Spoken North Saami is highly diverse, yet the written form is uniform. This can pose small problems in learning to write, since the writing system is not a phonemic transcription of each dialect (it is *one* writing system, not a family of writing systems). People cope with quirks like *ŧ, ŋ, dj, a ~ á*.

By its nature, a written language disregards highly-variable facts of speech. In addition, written languages change very slowly but spoken languages change very quickly. Written Kikuyu was invented about 150 years ago, ignoring variation in spoken language. It therefore is relatively uniform. There is a social and linguistic story behind the status of Kikuyu, as to why the written language is stable. Written Logoori was invented about 100 years ago, and is not very uniform. The two reasons for this difference are greater actual linguistic diversity, and negligible printed output (mainly Bible translations).

In other words, a "written language" is actually a different thing from a "spoken language". Linguists are mostly interested in spoken language though some linguists (whose who deal in dead languages) have no choice but to deal with written languages.

Comment: A statement is misleading when it leads you in a wrong direction. It doesn't require intent one way or the other on the part of the person making the statement.

Comment: That's not how the word misleading is used. "Unclear" is a neutral description, "misleading" implies that the author led you in a direction.